# SetContentView (when OnResume after OnPause) without see last content

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a application coded in Xamarin, Visual Studio C#. I want to show the main layout (homescreen.axml) when the user back to the application after onPause. My code is very simple and works ok but when back to the application the last layout is showed half second and then the main layout is showed, I'm using this code:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
  base.OnResume();
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.linterna);
}
```

Also I tried to SetContentView to change the layout in the onPause method but this don't do nothing. I'm a novice in android and don't have much idea of Activities, etc, programming in Windows is very very different.

Comment: Usually setContentView is only called in onCreate.

Comment: If you are more familiar with WPF/UWP, maybe you should take a look at either Xamarin.Forms or Uno instead? This would get you going so much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?
[image]

If so, you want to change the activity when your application from background to foreground, you should using following code in other activity.

```
 [Activity(Label = "Activity1")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        // Create your application here
    }
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();

        //  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

If you just set the `SetContentView()` in the `OnPause` or `OnResume`, it change the layout of current activity, all of the event will not be executed, For example, I change the code like following format.

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity1")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
        // Create your application here
    }
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();

         SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

Here is running gif.after set `SetContentView` to `activity_main`, it button click event is not work. Android pages consist of activities, not layout.xml
[image]